# Возможный довод в защиту буквы Ё

Tags: русская-графика

Мы все привыкли к тому, что в паре Е/Ё буква Е является главной. А может быть, всё наоборот?

У нас есть фонема О, которую фактически представляют три буквы – О, Ё и Е (например, суффикс ОВ/ЁВ/ЕВ). О пишется после твердых согласных, пара Ё/Е – после мягких согласных: Ё под ударением, а Е заменяет Ё безударной позиции. Но в современном языке именно Ё  составляет фонетическую пару О/Ё, а Е можно считать вспомогательным вариантом.

Конечно, Е – буква авторитетная, она не только выполняет половину работы за букву Ё, но и представляет фонему Э после мягких (и часто после твердых) согласных, то есть работы у нее хватает. Кроме того,  Е принадлежит исторический приоритет. Тем не менее в паре Е/Ё следовало бы букве Ё отдать должное и поставить ее на первое место. И уж, конечно, ОБОЗНАЧАТЬ НА ПИСЬМЕ.

Comment: Двумя  руками  ЗА  то,  чтобы  обозначать  Ё  на  письме.  Плюс  к  зтому  ударение  во  всех  словах,  как  у  греков.  Сколько  проблем  бы  исчезло !

Comment: 1. В общем, да. Проблем и разговоров на эту тему значительно больше, чем она этого заслуживает. Также не исключено, что букве Ё (а также обозначаемому ею "мягком" звуку О) просто НЕ ДАЮТ РАЗВИВАТЬСЯ в нормальный знак. Кроме того, хотелось бы как-то облегчить изучение русского языка для иностранных пользователей - это способствовало бы его распространению в мире.
2. Ударение желательно бы ставить при наличии вариантов, особенно если неправильный нужно исключить. И с буквами Э/Е тоже проблема - не помешал бы надстрочный знак для уже устоявшегося твердого Е (теннис, например).

Comment: 1. Можно обсудить политические проблемы, связанные с введением буквы "ё" в русский язык.

2. По моим сведениям, крупнейшая политическая акция, направленная на разобщение славян, угрожавших Византии, была осуществлена Кириллом и Мефодием.

Comment: C  ударением  проблемы  в  иноязычных  словах,  в  топонимах  как  наших,  так  и  не  наших,  в  личных  именах  и  т.д.  Ё  всегда  ударная,  Е  не  всегда.  Неправильно  обозначенный  звук - неправильное  ударение.  Да  и  для  твёрдого  Е  знак  надстрочный  не  помешал  бы,  согласен.

Comment: Читать  текст  с  проставленными  знаками  ударения  не  трудно,  у  меня  была  в  детстве  такая  книжка.  В  любом  случае  дело  привычки.

Comment: А  противников  буквы  Ё  я  вообще  не  понимаю - отсутствие  буквы  при  наличии  явного  звука - где  тут  положительные  моменты ?

Comment: Про "наличие явного звука" и "положительные моменты"

Лица, которым слон на ухо наступил, распознают "наличие" одинакового "явного звука" и в слове "ёлка" ("йолка"), и в слове "козёл" ("козьол").

По моим сведениям, украинцы не используют букву "ё" (например, из-за "отсутствия явного звука" в фамилии Рубльов).

Comment: Галактион, не очень понятно высказывание по поводу явных и неявных звуков. Фонема О включается в себя два фонетически разных звука (мягкий и твердый вариант). Акустически они значительно различаются , но оба относятся к одному знаку-фонеме. Это ее законные вариации. Наверное, в разных словах  "мягкий" О имеет отличительные особенности произношения, которые можно уловить на слух, но учитывать их не имеет смысла. Любое количество фонетических форм (в ударной позиции)  мы здесь приводим к двум обобщенным вариантам, которые и обозначаем буквами О и Ё.

Comment: София, кого ещё Вы имеете в виду под "мы" в предложении "Любое количество фонетических форм (в ударной позиции) мы здесь приводим к двум обобщенным вариантам, которые и обозначаем буквами О и Ё."?

P.S. Когда я употребляю местоимение "мы", то [я] имею в виду русских: русского [математика] Александра Островского, русского [путешественника] Фёдора Конюхова, русского [филолога] Алексея Шахматова, русского [мореплавателя] Петра Лазарева, русского [химика] Бориса Белоусова, русского [конструктора] Михаила Калашникова, ...

Comment: Извините, это я просто цитирую учебник для вузов. Это всё они, авторы, берут на себя смелость так считать. Но вы правы: следует выражаться корректно.

Comment: София, Вы верите, что в лесу в сильный мороз шестилетний русский [ребёнок] способен самостоятельно вести лошадь, запряжённую в сани с дровами?

Comment: Никак не могу привыкнуть  к "вариациям". Так Лесков и вспоминается. София,есть ли принципиальная разница между терминами варианты фонем и вариации фонем?

Comment: Это, я думаю, терминология московской фонологической школы. Варианты у них - это те звуки, которыми представлена фонема в слабых позициях, то есть, например, редуцированные гласные. Мне эти названия тоже не очень нравятся, как и вся история с сигнификативно и перцептивно слабыми и  сильными позициями. Ни выговорить, ни понять - ими никто и не пользуется на практике, только студентов учат. А вот понятия, которые эти слова обозначают, являются важными. Я бы их по-другому назвала, но кто же мне позволит.

Comment: Про детей. Верю, и легко. Это же не наши (современные) дети, а крестьянские. У них всё по-другому.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не могли бы сформулировать, что именно Вы доказываете или чего добиваетесь? 
Если изменения существующих орфографических правил, то искренне надеюсь, что никто Ваши рассуждения всерьез не воспримет. 
Ибо к орфографии это никак не относится. 
Давно уже сказано, что вопрос употребления Ё аналогичен вопросу об обязательной  простановке ударений во всех словах. Читать такие тексты - сущее мучение и нагрузка для глаз.

А кто там "главный" в парах - с этим в Думу.

> Использование буквы Ё не аналогично употреблению ударения. Об этом, в частности, говорит пример с Алехиным.

Почему не аналогично - и о чем говорит пример?
Я по-прежнему думаю, что именно аналогично - и пример с Алехиным это подтверждает (хотя и с некоторыми оговорками), но никак не опровергает. Никаких попыток переубедить меня у вас не наблюдаю.

> К сожалению, наши пользователи очень смутно понимают соотношение букв О/Е/Ё, (а здесь история переходит в современность), что плохо сказывается на орфографии тоже, просто напрямую переходит.

Кто такие ваши (или наши) пользователи, что есть соотношение букв - и почему первые должны понимать второе? Как все это сказывается на орфографии, даже и понять не пытаюсь.

> В младших классах (развивающей школы) было такое понятие - работа гласных букв. Сейчас об этом уже мало кто может рассуждать - и в старшей школе, и в последующих классах жизни тоже.

Мне это понятие незнакомо - потому и рассуждать о нем, естественно, не буду. Думаю, что таких, как я, большинство даже среди людей в высшей степени грамотных.

> Я ничего не добиваюсь - просто хотела обсудить тему.

Ну тогда надо хотя бы понятно сформулировать предмет обсуждения. Хотя само по себе бесцельное обсуждение тоже не слишком сближает.

> Про думу - смешно. Юмора здесь не хватает.

А мне вот другой раз плакать хочется от их словотворчества.

> Написано: Алехин, читаете: Алёхин, а он Алехин.

На сарае тоже написано. А там дрова лежат. Вы про это?

> Вы предположили, что буква Е заменяет Ё (ВЫПОЛНЯЕТ РАБОТУ ПО ОБОЗНАЧЕНИЮ МЯГКОГО ЗВУКА О), а она ВЫПОЛНЯЕТ СВОЮ СОБСТВЕННУЮ РАБОТУ - обозначает звук Э.

Чур меня, чур. Я такого не предполагал. Если Вы мне покажете мою фразу, которую Вы так смогли истолковать, то я поясню свою мысль.

> Работа - это, конечно, простецкий термин - для младших детей, но мало кто из "старших детей" может толково объяснить этот странный "триумвират" О/Ё/Е. И вследствие этого скоро будем писать чернеть - чорный, не понимая, что обозначаем.

Я повторяю, этот "триумвират", я тоже не могу объяснить, ибо вообще не понимаю, о чем речь. И наверное никто не может, кроме автора.

> А кто же все-таки главный?

Папа Римский. Помните Кассиля? "А если кит - и вдруг на слона, кто кого сборет?"
Ну скажите мне на милость, какая буква вообще "главная" в алфавите?

> В паре О/Ё буква О обозначает звук-фонему-доминанту О,

Что такое звук-фонема-доминанта? Звук и фонема - знаю, "доминанта" - могу понять, Все вместе - не понимаю.

> буква Ё обозначает мягкий О

Я не сторонник идеи назвать гласные "мягкими". Но если за этим не стоит ничего, кроме "звука О, пред которым идет мягкий согласный, то да". Хотя надо оговорить случай обозначения через Ё сочетания ЙО. Но какое это все имеет отношение к заявленной для обсуждения теме?

> - ее ВАРИАЦИЮ, а буква Е что там делает?

Не понимаю вопроса. Её - это чью? И что такое "вариация" (да еще заглавными)?

Comment: 1. Использование буквы Ё не аналогично употреблению ударения. Об этом, в частности,  говорит пример с Алехиным.
2. К сожалению, наши пользователи очень смутно понимают соотношение букв О/Е/Ё, (а здесь история переходит в современность), что плохо сказывается на орфографии тоже, просто напрямую переходит.
3. В младших классах (развивающей школы) было такое понятие - работа гласных букв. Сейчас об этом уже мало кто может рассуждать - и в старшей школе, и в последующих классах жизни тоже.
4. Я ничего не добиваюсь - просто хотела  обсудить тему.
5.  Про думу - смешно. Юмора здесь не хватает.

Comment: 1. Написано: Алехин, читаете: Алёхин, а он Алехин. Вы предположили, что буква Е заменяет Ё (ВЫПОЛНЯЕТ РАБОТУ ПО ОБОЗНАЧЕНИЮ МЯГКОГО ЗВУКА О), а она ВЫПОЛНЯЕТ СВОЮ СОБСТВЕННУЮ РАБОТУ - обозначает звук Э.
2. Работа - это, конечно, простецкий термин - для младших детей, но мало кто из "старших детей" может толково объяснить этот странный "триумвират" О/Ё/Е. И вследствие этого скоро будем писать чернеть - чорный, не понимая, что обозначаем.
3. А кто же все-таки главный? В паре О/Ё буква О обозначает звук-фонему-доминанту О, буква Ё обозначает мягкий О - ее ВАРИАЦИЮ, а буква Е что там делает?

Comment: Дорогой behemothus, я поздравляю Вас с наступающим Новым годом. Я желаю Вам в Новом году любви, удачи и понимания со стороны близких и не очень близких людей. Вы позволите мне ответить только на Ваш последний вопрос? В противном случае я просто боюсь, что наша беседа плавно перейдет в 2014 год.Итак, вариация (где тут мой "Справочник по современному русскому языку") - это вот что: "В сигнификативно сильных, но перцептивно слабых позициях фонема представлена своими вариациями". Надеюсь, вы не будете отрицать, что "мягкий" О - это именно этот случай.

Comment: И Вам не кашлять.
Автора справочника не назовете?
Я не буду отрицать ничего из того, чего не знаю. 
Но ведь и вы же не будете отрицать, что сия заумная фраза не имеет никакого отношения к орфографии? 
Как и того, Ваше "обсуждение" направлено именно на изменение действующих орфографических правил?!

ЗЫ Вообще-то мои вопросы были риторическими. Вопросов у меня нет кроме одного. Нафига оно все надо - ломать орфографию?
ЗЫЫ Интересно, сколько человек тут понимают фразу *"В сигнификативно сильных, но перцептивно слабых позициях фонема представлена своими вариациями"*. ))))

Comment: Я (впервые!) присоединяюсь к behemothus: ничего непонятно. А цитату из справочника ну разве что Людмила сможет расшифровать. А нам, простым смертным, хотелось бы на этом портале не для специалистов по-русски говорить.

Comment: Дорогие мои друзья - те, которые поддерживают и не поддерживают меня. Перед нами стоит задача не ломать орфографию, а защитить ее классический вариант, изложенный в 1956 году. Чтобы это сделать, надо иметь "серьезные" знания. Я привожу цитаты из справочника, чтобы показать, насколько высокая наука "страшно далека от народа" и ничего не дает практике. Например, я не хочу писать "чернеть - чорный", а мы скоро будем так писать. Потому что никто не хочет понять взаимосвязь букв О/Ё/Е, а без этого простейшая орфограмма "выбор О/Ё/Е после шипящих" не понимается практически никем.

Comment: >Перед нами стоит задача не ломать орфографию, а защитить ее классический вариант, изложенный в 1956 году.  
  
Тогда вообще разговора нет. Пишете Ё только там, где это предписано П-56. Т.е. в именах собственных, в изданиях для детей и иностранцев и для снятия неоднозначности ("все" и "всё", "ведро" и "вёдро" - других-то случаев и вспомнить трудно).   

>Я (впервые!) присоединяюсь к behemothus: ничего непонятно.   
    
Я должен этим гордиться?

Answer (score 1):

Буквы "е" и "ё" похожи по написанию, но это совершенно разные буквы. Противодействие введению обязательного употребления написанию буквы "ё" было всегда. Считалось. что "ёкать" - это как-то простонародно, люди возвышенные должны чураться буквы "ё": лучше не только писать, но и говорить "подледный", а не "подлёдный". Так оно как-то возвышеннее, благороднее и поэтичнее.
Даже Сталин не смог победить этот всероссийский сговор против буквы "ё". Возможно, кому-то из наших правителей удастся это сделать. А пока мы не только искажаем русский язык, но даже  в большинстве своём не знаем, что великий русский поэт вовсе не Фет, а Фёт.

Comment: Про Фёта впервые слышу (знаю только вариант Фэт).  Откуда, интересно, такие сведения - Фёт?

Comment: На Фёте настаивают в основном германофилы. Имхо. Но такая...  версия (не подберу слова) существует. Фамилия отца по-немецки писалась **Foeth**. Вопрос в том, достаточное ли это основание для написания и произношения "Фёт" на русском.    
(+)
В русском нет звука "О умляут". Есть некие резоны за то, что этот звук лучше передается буквой Ё чем Е. Но всё весьма спорно.

Answer (score 1):

Цитирую.

Биография

Родился в семье помещика Шеншина.

Фамилия Фет (точнее, Фёт, нем. Foeth) стала для поэта, как он впоследствии вспоминал, «именем всех его страданий и горестей». Сын орловского помещика Афанасия Неофитовича Шеншина (1775—-1855) и привезённой им из Германии Каролины Шарлотты Фёт, он был при рождении записан (вероятно, за взятку) законным сыном своих родителей, хотя родился через месяц после прибытия Шарлотты в Россию и за год до их брака. Когда ему было 14 лет, «ошибка» в документах обнаружилась, и он был лишён фамилии, дворянства и русского подданства и стал «гессендармштадтским подданным Афанасием Фётом»... (

Comment: А смысл? Ну коли уж так приспичило цитировать, хоть ссылку давайте на Вики.  
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D1%82,_%D0%90%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87

Answer (score 0):

Написание Фёт можно посмотреть, например, здесь: 
http://rpp.nashaucheba.ru/docs/index-90853.html